# "TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)" when trying to inherit from a base class with the same name as its module

Tags: python, inheritance, import, typeerror

I have the following project structure:

```
- equalizer
    - __init__.py
    - equalizer.py
    - lms.py
- main.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

`equalizer.py` defines a base class named `equalizer`, like so:

```
class equalizer:
    var1 = []
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.var1 = data
```

`lms.py` defines a child class `lms`, which derives from `equalizer`:

```
from equalizer import equalizer

class lms(equalizer):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(self, data)

    def lms(self):
        print('Hello World!')
```

Finally, in `main.py`, I instantiate the child:

```
import equalizer.lms as eq

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = []

    lms_eq = eq.lms(data= data)
    lms_eq.lms()
```

When I run the code starting from `main.py`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import equalizer.lms as eq
  File "C:\Users\...\equalizer\lms.py", line 6, in <module>
    class lms(equalizer):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `from equalizer import equalizer` is importing the *module* - equalizer.py in a folder named equalizer.  The actual class is one level deeper - `from equalizer.equalizer import equalizer` perhaps.  (And perhaps using the same name for everything isn't such a good idea...)

Comment: Maybe it's the matter of this example, but it's hard to read. Classes should have names starting with capital letters, there shouldn't be in general a method called the same as the class...

Comment: please don't name packages/modules/classes all the same, it's terribly confusing for no benefit.

Comment: I added an answer to the canonical for the error message, that should also clear up everything that's specific to your circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your life easier and have python class names as camel caps to distinguish them from the module.

The issue is right here:

```
from equalizer import equalizer
```

You didn't relative import the module, so this is more like:

```
from <package equalizer> import <equalizer.py>
```

You want:

```
from .equalizer import equalizer
```

Which makes it more akin to:

```
from <equalizer.py> import <class equalizer>
```